# Where is Xcode's "TOOLCHAINS" set?

Tags: swift, xcode

I upgraded my project from Swift 2.2 to 2.3 (Xcode 7 to 8), and committed everything on one Mac.  When I pulled from git on my other Mac, and built, I get:

```
Warning: target specifies SWIFT_VERSION = '2.3', but it is overridden by TOOLCHAINS = 'com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault'
```

I can't find anything called "TOOLCHAINS" in any file.  What's this warning mean?

Answer (score 9):

I see you have solved the problem by upgrading to Swift 3.0.

I encountered the same problem, and did some research in this.
When building within Xcode, make sure you have the setting **" Project > Build Settings > Use Legacy Swift Language Version"** set to 
**"Yes"**

For those who are using **xcrun** or **xcodebuild** tools, I managed to solve it by using an extra option  '**toolchain**'

```
xcrun --toolchain "com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_2_3"
xcodebuild -toolchain "com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_2_3"
```

The identifier **"com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_2_3"** can be found at:

```
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/Swift_2.3.xctoolchain/ToolchainInfo.plist
```

Hope this helps for those who are developing in Swift 2.3.

Source: https://marc.ttias.be/swift-users/2016-08/msg00188.php

Comment: if somebody is using fastlane, this gym option will do same thing: `toolchain: "swift_2_3"`

Answer (score 8):

I had the same warning and i could solve the problem by cleaning the build folder (alt+shift+cmd+K)

Answer (score 7):

Toolchains is not explicitly called out as it was in the prior builds.  However, it is still there in the **Locations** -> **Command Line Tools** portion of the *Xcode Preferences* menu

Choosing **Xcode 8** resolved the issue for me.

[image]

Comment: I spent a week and upgraded my app to Swift 3, so I can't confirm that this helps, but at least it's plausible, so thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have "Toolchain" option under Xcode menu, you need to [download](https://www.swift.org/download/#snapshots) and install a snapshot or release first.

Answer (score 1):

Toolchains are set under the Xcode menu then Toolchains. It should be set to Xcode 8. There is also a build setting in Xcode 8 called "Use legacy swift version" that should be set to YES so that you use Swift 2.3 instead of 3.

Comment: In Xcode 8.0 (8A218a), there is no "Toolchains" under the Xcode menu.

Comment: @J.Cocoe is this  Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools ?