# Using Swift 3.0.0 for the new XCode

Tags: swift

I was wondering if it is possible to compile my project using Swift 3.0.0 instead of Swift 3.0.2? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: Because one of my projects that I haven't touched in a long while is in Swift 3.0.0 and a lot of the libraries it depends on aren't updated.

Comment: There are no significant changes between these two versions. Why wouldn't these libraries support the new version?

Comment: It used to be that Xcode had a toolchain option. I can't find it - maybe it's only available in Xcode betas? Anyways, you *can* build your project from a command line using an older Swift toolchain (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884323/where-is-xcodes-toolchains-set) **but** I'm not finding a Swift 3.0.0 download available (https://swift.org/download/#releases), so unless you can find a copy this route is a dead end.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it, I'm getting a lot of syntactic errors.

Comment: It will work properly, if u have files written in swift 2 then there is a real monster waiting for you. Make sure u are using xcode 8+