# Xcode 9.3 cannot submit build to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, bitcode

I've just updated to Xcode 9.3 and am having the following issue when submitting my app to the app store:

Invalid Bundle - The app cannot be processed because options not allowed to be embedded in bitcode are detected in the submission. It is likely that you are not building the app with the toolchain provided in Xcode. Rebuild your entire app with the latest GM Xcode and submit the app again.

I've double checked and all the frameworks linked to my project and they have all been compiled with bitcode enabled. Only one of these frameworks is a Carthage framework and I've ensured that it's been rebuilt using `carthage update`.

I'm completely stumped and don't know what else to try.
Thanks ahead for your help!

Comment: Are you sure you are using latest GM Xcode and not Xcode 9.3 beta? If its latest Xcode then set the Command Line Tools to latest Xcode like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39967084/5866353 and then rebuild and try to submit the app.

Comment: Hi Sharath, I've double checked and the command line tool is properly set to Xcode 9.3. It can't be the beta version as this was updated through the App Store today. If I go to about Xcode there is no mention of this being a beta version of Xcode.

Comment: I've had to turn of bitcode for the submission, and then the build went through. This is far from ideal but it'll keep me going until Apple gets back to me on the bug reporter.

Comment: Reinstalling Xcode also didn't work.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that when I disable the  bitcode in build settings, submission went thorough... Apple I am so tired of you!!!

Comment: I can confirm having same problem, seems that the only solution is turning bitcode off

Answer (score 2):

> ITMS-90562: Invalid Bundle - The app cannot be processed because options not allowed to be embedded in bitcode are detected in the submission. It is likely that you are not building the app with the toolchain provided in Xcode. Rebuild your entire app with the latest GM Xcode and submit the app again.

This error might be caused by one of your external frameworks. You can try to rebuild the app from bitcode by yourself and that might give you some more informations. To do that in Xcode archive your app, then in organizer, in archives tab click "Distribute App", select "Development", and after that select "Rebuild from Bitcode" and proceed. After that Xcode will probably show more extended information about the problem which might help you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, using Apple's latest toolchain, when including a dynamic framework built with hidden symbols (`ld` options `-bitcode_bundle -bitcode_hide_symbols -r -x`).

When the symbols weren't hidden, the app was processed by Apple as expected.